# Display google map for multiple locations

Tags: odoo-14

Sales person will visit different locations in a day and coordinates will store with location name in a model.

I want to display google map for a sales person showing all location on map along with complete path.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q96Mv.png)